# JavaScript Intl/BCP 47: How to use ISO date format `yyyy-mm-dd` for German locales instead of `dd.mm.yyyy`?

Tags: javascript, date, internationalization, intl

Germany uses two different date formats:

- modern (not used very often, ISO-8601): 2022-01-31
- classical (used by most Germans): 31.01.2022

JavaScript's `Intl` API uses the "classical" date format for locale `de-DE`:

```js
// This prints out: 31.01.2022
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit'
}).format(new Date(2022, 0, 31)));
```

Please find here the demo: [» Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC9EhgWhAHN0xYB3AAgEkwAXaeAEWSdgBUBLAW1gAxEKn6d0AcgAmsALRsAopIA0tAN65atAJ6w0ALlqSwAV0GpewVVtr9wTABZHJAJjnTeZXkxvbpyDou7p7evrgAvpjwAGai4kyUNLQcXOiuAAyurmoZagDMAIyYJXhAA)

Is it somehow possible to use the "modern" (= ISO-8601) date format with Intl by just extending the locale in the example above ('de-DE...')? Using the locale `de-DE-u-ca-iso8601` for example is not working.

BTW: Using `Date.prototype.toISOString` is NOT an option.
[Edit] It's also NOT an option to just use a locale for a different country.

[Edit] I hoped to find a answer somewhere [here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#UnicodeCalendarIdentifier) or [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/bcp47/calendar.xml), but have not found a solution there.

[Edit] You can configure the time format by the locale string:
`en-GB` (shows 24 hour time format)
`en-GB-u-hc-h12` (shows 12 hour time format, adding am/pm)
... so I hoped something similar to this would also be possible with 'dd.mm.yyyy' vs 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Comment: Why `Date.prototype.toISOString` is not an option?

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski  This is used inside of a JavaScript library where all date formatting is done by using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` and date formats are only configurable by `locale` and `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions`.

Comment: For what it's worth, the whole purpose of tools like Intl and ICU is to avoid having to fiddle with utterly complicated locale data nobody can possibly master. I wish the associated documentation was more accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Use `en-CA` as locale</strike>.

Afaik there is no specific locale to format into the 'modern' (iso) date string.

Either split and reorder the date string, use `formatToParts` instead of `format` or split the result of `Date.toISOString` may be other ideas.

**Note** (nov 2023): I have created a small library ([es-date-fiddler](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)) that may be useful.

```js
// 1. locale 'en-CA' (not an option as per comment)
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(`en-CA`, {
    year: `numeric`, month: `2-digit`, day: `2-digit`})
  .format(new Date(2022, 0, 31)));

// 2. split and reorder the result
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(`de-DE`, {
    year: `numeric`, month: `2-digit`, day: `2-digit`})
  .format(new Date(2022, 0, 31))
  .split(`.`)
  .reverse()
  .join(`-`) );


// 3. use formatToParts
const reformatGerman = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(`de-DE`, {
    year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'})
  .formatToParts(new Date(2022, 0, 31))
  .filter( v => ~[`year`, `month`, `day`].indexOf(v.type) ) 
  .reduce( (acc, val) => ({...acc, [val.type]: val.value}), {} );
console.log(`${
  reformatGerman.year}-${
  reformatGerman.month}-${
  reformatGerman.day}`);

// 4. truncate the result of `toISOString()`
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 31))
  .toISOString().split(`T`)[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But just using a different language/country is not an option as this will have negative side effect on number formatting, translations etc.. That's why I've written "[...] by just extending the locale in the example above ('de-DE...')". I'll add this as constraint to my question to make this more clear.